# Cannot put a text value in a xls file using aspose.cell for android

Tags: android, excel, aspose

I use an Edittext in android to fill a cell of xls.file by using aspose-cell for android API. But when i put some text in the edittext, the displayed value in the xls. file is always the same : 2131492965 !! and not the text of the edittext.

Can you help me ?

Here is my code :

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.lionel.cells;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.aspose.cells.Cell;
import com.aspose.cells.Cells;
import com.aspose.cells.*;
import com.aspose.cells.Workbook;
import com.aspose.cells.Worksheet;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;


import java.io.File;

import static com.aspose.cells.b.b.zp.v;
import static com.example.lionel.cells.R.id.button1;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */

public   EditText mEditText;
public String text;


//  public String text = textview.getText().toString();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LibsLoadHelper.loadLibs(getApplicationContext());
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edittext1);

   //        mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener()
   //        {
   //            @Override
   //            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent      keyEvent) {
  //
  //                if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyCode)
  //                {
  //                    if(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP == keyEvent.getAction())
  //                    {
  //                        EditText editText = (EditText)view;
  //                        mCellValue = editText.getText().toString();
 //                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mCellValue,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 //                    }
 //                    return true;
 //                }
 //                return false;
 //            }
 //        });

    text = mEditText.getText().toString();
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new TestTask().execute();
        }
    });


}

}
```

TestTask.java :

```
package com.example.lionel.cells;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.aspose.cells.Cell;
import com.aspose.cells.Cells;
import com.aspose.cells.Workbook;
import com.aspose.cells.Worksheet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import static com.example.lionel.cells.R.id.text;

/**
* Created by Lionel on 25/09/2016.
*/





public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

//    File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File sdDir  =         Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
String sdPath = sdDir.getAbsolutePath();





@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {


    Boolean result = false;

    Workbook book = new Workbook();
    Worksheet sheet = book.getWorksheets().get(0);
    Cells cells = sheet.getCells();
    Cell cell = cells.get("A1");
    Cell cell1 = cells.get("A2");
    Cell cell2 = cells.get("A3");

    cell.putValue(text);
    cell1.setValue(true);
    cell2.setValue(123);

    try {
        book.save(sdPath + "/output.xlsx");
//
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Krukiou, 
A similar inquiry of yours have already been replied in Aspose.Cells support forum. Please check the following piece of code as well as [this](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/787644/cannot-put-a-value-of-an-editext-in-a-xls-file.aspx) thread for details.

Regarding the following snippet, it uses the mCellValue variable to load the contents of the EditText field on Enter key. You can use the same variable to insert the contents of the EditText field to the spreadsheet cell using the UI button mButton. Moreover, as by default, the EditText can span over multiple lines therefore the Enter key on the real device (or soft keyboard) will act as carriage return, therefore the code sets the EditText.SingleLine as true in order to change the behaviour of the soft Enter key.

```
private TextView mResultTextView;
private TextView mProgressTextView;
private Button mButton;
private EditText mEditText;
private String mCellValue;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
LibsLoadHelper.loadLibs(getApplicationContext());

mResultTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result_textview);
mProgressTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress_textview);
mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
mEditText.setSingleLine(true);

mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

        if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyCode)
        {
            if(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP == keyEvent.getAction())
            {
                EditText editText = (EditText)view;
                mCellValue = editText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mCellValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
mButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new TestTask().execute();

    }
});
```

*Note: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.*

Comment: Hi, by adding EditText.SingleLine (true), the code is working. Thanks you for your help.